# Checking multiple columns are all zeors

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to check if specific columns are all zeros
below works fine as I check the column 11

```
        if ((df.iloc[:, 11] == 0).all() == True):
```

however if I want to check column 11~17, it has error

```
        if ((df.iloc[:, 11:17] == 0).all() == True):
```

saying:

```
raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() 
or a.all().
```

why is that? and how should I fix it?

Comment: see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score 3):

you can try:

```
(df.iloc[:, 11:17] == 0).all()
```

The above code will give you a Series of boolean values

In your if condition you can use:

```
if (df.iloc[:, 11:17] == 0).all().all():
    #your code
```

**OR**

```
if (df.iloc[:, 11:17] == 0).all(None)
    #your code
```

**Note:** you are getting `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous` error because `(df.iloc[:, 11:17] == 0).all()` gives you a boolean Series instead of a scaler boolean value so to fix this we chain another `all()` method to it so if all of the value satisfy the condition `df.iloc[:, 11:17] == 0` only then it will give you `True`

Comment: What happens when you do `(df.iloc[:, 11:17] == 0).all(None)`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist got it sir..Thanks **:)**